# AsyncTask onPostExecute not reliable

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an async task, which has a very simple doInbackground and onPostExecute. 
For some reasons, i see the PostExecute method being called, and at some very rare times, it gets skipped from being called. This results in unexpected flow in my application. Given that it gets called most of the times, i know the syntax and parameters are right. I also dont "cancel" my asynctask any time. So, why does it get skipped?

```
private class ViewStoppedAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public ViewStoppedAsync() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ViewStopped - doInBackground");
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ViewStopped - onPostExecute");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        <<my code>>
    }

            private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    Log.v(TAG, "releaseMediaPlayer()");
    try {
        videoView.stopPlayback();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Handled: releaseMediaPlayer videoView.stopPlayback() - " + e, e);
    }
    if (mp != null) {
        try {
            mp.stop();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Handled: releaseMediaPlayer mp.stop() - " + e, e);
        } finally {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Without a complete example (rather than useless `<<my code>>`), and without evidence of it being skipped (e.g., the complete LogCat showing your logging statements, along with surrounding statements that might give us some clues), it is unlikely that anyone can help you.

Comment: I have added code that is executed during doInBackground. As you can see i am trying to stop a videoplayback and release the mediaplayer. For some reasons, video.stopplayback, doesnt really clear the mediaplayer properly. so i am having some recheck code.

Comment: I fail to see why you are doing this work on a background thread in the first place.

Comment: mediaplayer.reset(_reset native function) resulted in ANRs when i tried to play a list of videos in a loop. Hence i had to move it to a background thread.